What is the relationship between sampling pulse width and pulse area, and do both influence the ability to reconstruct the signal?
Lathi made the following statement in problem 8.2-7

In the text, for sampling purposes, we used
timelimited narrow pulses such as impulses
or rectangular pulses of width less than the
sampling interval T. Show that it is not necessary
to restrict the sampling pulse width. We can use
sampling pulses of arbitrarily large duration and
still be able to reconstruct the signal x(t) as long
as the pulse rate is no less than the Nyquist rate
for x(t).

However, he also said in Drill 8.2 that

The Role of Sampling Pulse Area
Show that the basic pulse p(t) used in the sampling pulse train in Fig. 8.4c cannot have zero
area if we wish to reconstruct x(t) by lowpass-filtering the sampled signal.

I have two questions.
First, from what I have understood, the longer the duration of each pulse, the wider the sampling pulse width, and thus the larger the sampling area, is this understanding correct or not?
Secondly, if the answer is yes for the first question, then why Lathi says
"it is not necessary to restrict the sampling pulse width  be able to reconstruct the signal x(t) as long
as the pulse rate is no less than the Nyquist rate
for x(t).",
but
"the basic pulse p(t) cannot have zero
area if we wish to reconstruct x(t) by lowpass-filtering the sampled signal."
for which they seem to contradict to each other?


First, from what I have understood, the longer the duration of each pulse, the wider the sampling pulse width, and thus the larger the sampling area, is this understanding correct or not?

It is incorrect. The area is determined both by the length and the shape of the pulse. If you double the length and half the height you still have the same area. For non rectangular pulses, the area is determined by the integral over the pulse shape.

for which they seem to contradict to each other?

Where is the contradiction? One statement is about the repetition rate of the pulses, the other one about their shape. These are completely independent from each other.

Then what is the reason for the basic pulse p(t) cannot have zero area if we wish to reconstruct x(t) by lowpass-filtering the sampled signal?

@TongSu: Sorry, we don't give direct answers to home work questions. Please show your work so far and tell us where you are stuck.
